# Change < Formik > to useFormik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, formik

I am using Formik/Yup for a validation of a page, which calls a GraphQL mutation. My code works fully:

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved ,setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation(RemoveUserMutation);

  function submitForm(email: string) {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
        variables: {
            email: email,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      setIsRemoved(true);
      console.log('info: ', data.deleteUser);
    })
    .catch((error: { message: string; }) => {
      setIsRemoved(false);
      console.log("Error msg:" + error.message);
      setErrorMessage(error.message)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);           
          };
          return (
            <div className='main-content'>
              <form style={{ width: '100%' }}
               onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();submitForm(email)
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <Button
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isValid || !email}
                  >
                    Remove User</Button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <br></br>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isRemoved, errorMessage)}
            </div>
          )
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, now I want to use `useFormik` hook instead of `<Formik>` and I am unable to do so. I have seen the following example but I just can't figure out how exactly I could syntactically use it in my case since I am using material ui components instead of formic-specific inputs.

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormik

Edit:

This compiles and all but there's no validation happening on the textfields. What am I missing?

```
export const schema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Invalid Email')
    .required('This Field is Required'),
});


export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation<DeleteUserResponse>(REMOVE_USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<DeleteUserResponse>) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
          setIsRemoved(true);
          console.log('info: ', data.deleteUser);
        }
      })
      .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
        setIsRemoved(false);
        console.log('Error msg:' + error.message);
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      });
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues:{ email: '' },
    onSubmit:(values, actions) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        },
       validationSchema:{schema}
    })

    const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
      const {name,value} = e.target;
      formik.setFieldValue(name,value);
     }

  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
            <Wrapper>
              <Form
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(formik.values.email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={formik.touched.email ? formik.errors.email : ''}
                    error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={formik.values.email}
                    //onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!formik.values.email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </Form>
              <br></br>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isRemoved, errorMessage)}
              </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It gave me this error:

```
TypeError: schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate'] is not a function. (In 'schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate'](validateData, {
    abortEarly: false,
    context: context
  })', 'schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate']' is undefined)
```

Secondly, earlier on, I was using `isValid`for the button but now it gives an error. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Hey @FSJ. Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get a lot more traction on this question if you make an attempt first. After you do, I'd love to help you out. React Hooks can be challenging to wrap your head around, I suggest starting with something simple.

Comment: Hello, could you please see the updated qs? I was wrapping formik before the last return but it just gives syntax errors. @JoeHawkins

Comment: You cannot call `useFormik` from inside of the JSX. Hooks are only allowed to be used at the beginning of functional components. Additionally, the way you are using the `useFormik` hook is invalid JSX. The Formik documentation has a good example of how to use the `useFormik` hook. Study this example by reading it and adding or removing form fields then apply it to your code. https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormik

Answer (score 4):

### Most of the time, you don't use the useFormik hook directly, which is not design for general use case.

I think this is stressed again in the document which is not intented for general usecase.
Please use `<Formik>` instead of the hook.
Comment by the author: Jared Palmer himself.

I have tag some issues here:

https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1722#issue-475725015
https://github.com/formium/formik/pull/1717#issuecomment-516867884

### Previously

Like Jow Hawkins has mentioned it will be quite overwhelming to learn about hooks, but I will provide you some changes and answer to help you start.

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved ,setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation(RemoveUserMutation);

  function submitForm(email: string) {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
        variables: {
            email: email,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      setIsRemoved(true);
      console.log('info: ', data.deleteUser);
    })
    .catch((error: { message: string; }) => {
      setIsRemoved(false);
      console.log("Error msg:" + error.message);
      setErrorMessage(error.message)
    })
  }

const formik = useFormik({
initialValues:{ email: '' },
onSubmit:(values, actions) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
      }, 1000);
    },
   validationSchema:schema
})

// depend on the return value
const handleSubmit = (someReturnValue or event)=>{
// if the return event has name
// such as event.target.name then you got the name
// and try event.target.value 
// then set field value

// eg: const value = event.current.value

formik.setFieldValue(name, value)
}

// dont forget to set onBlur as well
// this i will leave it to you

  return (
    <div>
      <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
      
            <div className='main-content'>
              <form style={{ width: '100%' }}
               onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={formik.touched.email ? formik.errors.email : ""}
                    error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={formik.values.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <Button
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isValid || !email}
                  >
                    Remove User</Button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <br></br>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isRemoved, errorMessage)}
            </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit:
Since you are using Material Ui textfield
add a `handleChange` method

```
const handleChange = (event)=>{
 // get name and value from event.target
 // is the same as const name = event.target.name
 const {name,value} = event.target
 // make sure you have name prop in 
 // your textfield and it is same name as your initial state
 formik.setFieldValue(name,value) // this call formik to set your value
}
```

then in your email component
`onChange={handleChange}`

Comment: Hey, did you get a chance to look at the updated qs?

Comment: For sure, your problem is unable to change the state right.

Comment: You can use formik.setFieldValue(varName, varValue), change is undefined because you never define it. you can do it like this check the latest edit.

Comment: Can you see my edited code? It compiles and works on the front-end but there's no validation happening on the text fields. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to define your schema. `validationSchema:schema`,

Comment: Your schema should be const schema = (values)=>{....validation, and then return true if valid}

Comment: The schema is already defined, imported from another file. Sorry, the edit wasn't made last time

Comment: use validationSchema:schema instead of validationSchema:{schema}